# dispatch is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, dispatch

So I've made sure that I `connect` my `mapDispatchToProps` properly and have bound the functions (I think) properly and also made sure there's no typo.

But for some reason the following code giving me dispatch is not a function error:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import aboutScreen from './About';
import settingScreen from './Setting';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from '../../auth/scenes/Login';
import * as authAction from '../../auth/actions';
import * as homeAction from '../actions';

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actionsHome: bindActionCreators(homeAction, dispatch),
  actionsAuth: bindActionCreators(authAction, dispatch)
});

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
  <View>
     <DrawerItems {...props}/>
     <Button title="Logout" onPress={()=>props.screenProps()}/>
  </View>
);

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    About: {
      screen: aboutScreen
    },
    Setting:{
      screen: settingScreen
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
  }
);

class DrawNav extends React.Component{  
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onSignOut = this.onSignOut.bind(this);
  }

  onSuccess() {
    this.props.actionsHome.successSignOut();
    Actions.reset("Auth");
  }

  onError(error) {
    Alert.alert('Oops!', error.message);
  }

  onSignOut() {
    this.props.actionsAuth.signOut(this.onSuccess.bind(this),this.onError.bind(this))
  }

  render(){
      return <Drawer screenProps = {this.onSignOut}/>;  
  }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps) (DrawNav);
```

I tried similar setup on my Home component and it worked. This is just pretty much a copy n paste from the Home logout schematics because I need a logout button on my drawer instead of Home.

Can anyone help me point out what did I miss here?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (DrawNav);`

`mapDispatchToProps` should be the second argument to your `connect` method.

The parameter provided to the first function argument in `connect` will be `state`, and the second argument function will be given `dispatch`

In your example, because your `mapDispatchToProps` is the first argument in `connect`, it is receiving `state` as it's argument. Then your `bindActionCreators` will try and invoke it as a function which is what's throwing your error.

Comment: passing `()=>{}` in place of `mapStateToProps` was not successful because connect was expecting plain object returned, but did help me get insight of what I did wrong, I guess I didn't read the `connect()` docs correctly and just assume I can get away with passing just `mapDispatchToProps` straight up like that. I ended up just doing `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (DrawNav);` and it worked perfectly! Thankyou so much!

Comment: Ah you're correct. I've updated my answer to ensure it returns.